# Architecture AWS get user or user pools in Gateway or Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

i would like to get some tips how I can solve the following issue.

The situation:

- **Backend** is running by AWS by ***lambda*** (Python)
- **REST-Interface** i am using ***API Gateway***
- **Authorization** of course via Cognito

**And now the issue**.
I have more u**ser pools**. In which pools is the user assign he/she get the date from different table (something as subsidiary).

The questions is, how i can identify in which pools belong the user. Is it possible to make this descision on the level of API Gateway and send to lamba function some string?

Thank you very much

Comment: It is not super clear what you are asking. Am I rephrasing right: you want to do something in your lambda code depending on which pool the authorized user belongs to?

Comment: If that's right, what you want is probably lambda proxy integration - it will give you an `event` object that contains all the stuff about the request, incluing authorization context. These [two](https://repost.aws/questions/QUdDG-PiUDT2qpZ4ZLh_puHg/how-to-pass-cognito-user-info-to-a-lambda-function) [links](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) might help.